# ¿cómo puedo hacer funcionar mi NS1.ejemplo.com con mi dominio recién comprado?

Tags: dns, centos

Soy propietario de un dominio "ejemplo.com" comprado en GoDaddy, además tengo una IP que tiene un servicio DNS funcionando. En ese servidor DNS tengo configurado un CName para NS1 apuntando a la IP publica que tiene este servicio (el mismo).

Cuando ingreso a GoDaddy y coloco NS1.ejemplo.com no funciona... no conozco mucho como funciona este servicio, estoy trabajando con Bind9 y CentOS 7.

Agradecería mucho una ayuda con esto, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando cambias una entrada DNS, en este caso añadir "NS1", suele tardar tiempo en actualizarse, hasta 48 horas. No sé si es el caso, pero igual es cuestión de esperar. Si en tu equipo cliente modificas el fichero hosts, añadiendo temporalmente la entrada, si es lo que comento, debería funcionar. Quita la entrada en el fichero hosts cuando acabes la prueba y espera.

Si no es lo comentado anteriormente, en los proveedores de hosting, hay que asociar esa entrada dns con el hosting. Es decir, el servidor web donde está alojada tu página tiene que saber que debe atender las peticiones de esa nueva dirección. Si el DNS y el hosting están en el mismo servicio de hosting (Gandi) tiene que hacerse de forma sencilla.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo de los DNS es que... ¿qué pasa si mas de una persona configura un dns cualquier con NS1 apuntando a mi dominio? ¿si después ingreso a mi proveedor de dominio e ingreso ns1.ejemplo.com como mi NS no será un problema? Weird...